# MySQL Having Clause and Count()

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, having-clause

I've got the following table and I'm trying to retrieve every:
name, descr, stock, address, postalcode & the city

where stock of item1 is > 10 AND stock of item2 is > 10 AND stock of item3 > 5

so I don't want the rows that only contain item1 and item2, like the ones with ID = 2

The rows of ID = 1 also won't fit because item1 its stock is < 10

Which means only rows of ID 3 and ID 4 match. But I don't want to see 6 rows, I just need two! containing the name, descr, stock, address, postalcode , city

```
| ID | NAME | DESCR | STOCK | ADDRESS | POSTALCODE | CITY |
|  1  |  foo  |  item1 |  5 |  addr1 |  po1 | city1 |
| 1  | foo  | item2 | 10 | addr1 | po1 | city1 |
| 1  | foo  | item3 | 5 | addr1 | po1 | city1 |
| 2  | bar  | item1 | 40 | addr2 | po1 | city1 |
| 2  | bar  | item2 | 30 | addr2 | po1 | city1 |
| 3  | smth  | item1 | 25 | addr3 | po3 | city1 |
| 3  | smth  | item2 | 20 | addr3 | po3 | city1 |
| 3  | smth  | item3 | 10 | addr3 | po3 | city1 |
| 4  | els  | item1 | 45 | addr4 | po4 | city1 |
| 4  | els  | item2 | 30 | addr4 | po4 | city1 |
| 4  | els  | item3 | 10 | addr4 | po4 | city1 |
```

I think I need something like:

```
SELECT name, descr, stock , address, postalcode, city
FROM table1
WHERE (descr like 'item1' AND stock >10) 
OR (descr like 'item2' AND stock >10) OR (descr like 'item3' AND stock >5)
GROUP BY name, descr, stock , address, postalcode, city
HAVING COUNT(distinct(somethingIdidNotFigureOutYet)) > 2
```

I tried to count the id, the name and even the description but it is not right. Could someone help me out with this one please. Thank you! (and sorry for the ugly table formatting)

Comment: What two rows do you want to see, when six rows match your conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I usually approach problems like this is breaking them down into smaller groups, and then combining queries as necessary. Let's consider a few things:

- Stock of item 1, item 2 must be greater than 10 and stock of item 3 must be greater than 5.

We can pull for rows that meet those requirements like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM myTable
GROUP BY id
HAVING 
  SUM(CASE WHEN descr = 'item1' THEN stock else 0 END) > 10 AND 
  SUM(CASE WHEN descr = 'item2' THEN stock else 0 END) > 10 AND 
  SUM(CASE WHEN descr = 'item3' THEN stock else 0 END) > 5;
```

This will return ids 3 and 4. Coincidentally, this will also work to meet the condition that we must have at least one item1, item2, and item3, since we used 'AND' in our having clause, which is what caused it to exclude id 2.

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ba81/1) example.

Comment: `DISTINCT` in your query is pretty useless

Comment: I suppose it is once I added the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @McAdam331 Thank you very much! worked like a charm. Also I would like to everybody else for their effort!

Answer (score 1):

Given the `WHERE` filter in this case, you could restrict the resultset groups to those `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT descr) = 3` (or if `descr` is necessarily unique in each group, simply `HAVING COUNT(*) = 3`).

A more general solution might however be to explicitly verify that each criterion is satisfied by each group:

```
HAVING SUM(descr = 'item1' AND stock > 10)
   AND SUM(descr = 'item2' AND stock > 10)
   AND SUM(descr = 'item3' AND stock >  5)
```

This works because the boolean expressions within each `SUM()` evaluate to `1` if true and `0` if false; so taking the `SUM()` over each group results in `0` if false for all records or non-zero if true for any (and when used in the boolean context of the `AND` operations / `HAVING` clause, yields the desired result).

Whilst the resultset would be unaffected, I'd nevertheless retain the `WHERE` clause for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `descr` from `select` and `group by` and add it to `Having` clause to filter the groups

Try this.

```
SELECT ID,
       NAME, 
       stock, 
       address, 
       postalcode, 
       city 
FROM   table1 
WHERE  ( descr IN ( 'item1', 'item2' ) 
         AND stock > 10 ) 
        OR ( descr = 'item3' 
             AND stock > 5 ) 
GROUP  BY ID,
          NAME, 
          stock, 
          address, 
          postalcode, 
          city 
HAVING Count(DISTINCT descr) = 3
```

**Note:** Using `LIKE` operator without *wildcard's* doesn't make more sense so, I have changed it to `=` operator

Answer (score 1):

If you want the names and address information, then you can use a `HAVING` clause but you also have to fix the `GROUP BY` clause.  Here is an example:

```
SELECT name, address, postalcode, city
FROM table1
GROUP BY name, address, postalcode, city
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN descr like 'item1' THEN stock END) > 10 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN descr like 'item2' THEN stock END) > 10 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN descr like 'item3' THEN stock END) > 5;
```

Note:  I have just moved all the conditions to the `HAVING` clause so the filtering logic is in one place.  You can repeat it in the `WHERE` clause if you like.

Then, if you want the descriptions and stock amounts, one method is a list:

```
SELECT name, address, postalcode, city,
       GROUP_CONCAT(descr, ':', stock SEPARATOR '; ') as items
FROM table1
GROUP BY name, address, postalcode, city
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN descr like 'item1' THEN stock END) > 10 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN descr like 'item2' THEN stock END) > 10 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN descr like 'item3' THEN stock END) > 5;
```

If you want the original rows, then I would suggest `IN` or `EXISTS`:

```
select t.*
from table1 t
where exists (select 1
              from table1 t1
              where t1.id = t.id and t1.descr = 'item1' and t1.stock > 10
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from table1 t1
              where t1.id = t.id and t1.descr = 'item2' and t1.stock > 10
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from table1 t1
              where t1.id = t.id and t1.descr = 'item3' and t1.stock > 5
             ) and
      t.descr in ('item1', 'item2', 'item3');
```

Note:  this version assumes that items are not repeated for a given `id`.  The first version doesn't make this assumption.

Comment: Is there a benefit to using `CASE WHEN descr LIKE 'item1'` instead of `WHEN descr = 'item1'` or was it just personal preference?

Comment: @McAdam331 . . . I almost never use the simple `case` statement because I've found too often that the logic needs to be modified to a searched case.  It is simpler just to write the searched case version the first time.

Comment: That makes sense, so it's more 'scalable' in that regard, easier to change in the future?

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you very much! I really appreciate it !!